# Pageres not working on Amazon Linux

Tags: aws

I have Amazon Linux and I installed `npm` using epel repository. After `npm` I installed `pageres` with

```
npm install --global pageres-cli
```

I already have a `phantomjs` version `1.9.8`

When I try to run `pageres` it is giving me this error:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/pageres-cli/node_modules/pageres/node_modules/mem/index.js:36
memoized.cache = opts.cache || new Map();
^
ReferenceError: Map is not defined
at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/pageres-cli/node_modules/pageres/node_modules/mem/index.js:36:41)
at Object. (/usr/lib/node_modules/pageres-cli/node_modules/pageres/dist/util.js:452:35)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object. (/usr/lib/node_modules/pageres-cli/node_modules/pageres/dist/index.js:213:48)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

I don't know how to fix this please let me know.

Regards,
Mansur

Answer (score 0):

The error was related to node version pageres required v0.12 but by using package manager installed node version is v0.10 i have fixed the issue with below steps.

[root@ifr4 ~]# wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.13.1/install.sh

[root@ifr4 ~]# chmod +x install.sh

[root@ifr4 ~]# ./install.sh

[root@ifr4 ~]# nvm list-remote

[root@ifr4 ~]# nvm install v0.12.0

[root@ifr4 ~]# nvm use v0.12.0

[root@ifr4 ~]# pageres google.com

✔ Generated 1 screenshot from 1 url and 1 size